# Cakephp How to validate an array to make sure that it has at least five items or more

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Hie guys i need help with my code. I have a form where a student selects subjects, marks and grades they obtained. Subjects and grades are a dropdown menu and they are in a loop. I want a student to enter at least five subjects including english language. each subject is referenced by a subject code. Can you help me do this?

My Controller function is

```
subject_code' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['subject_code'][$i],
'grade' =>  $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['grade'][$i],
```

My model is as follows

```
public $validate = array(
'grade' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notempty'),
        // extra keys like on, required, etc. go here...
    ),
    'ruleName2' => array(
        'rule' => array('inList', array('A', 'B','C','D','E')),
        'message' => 'Not in range.',
    ),
),
'subject_code' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: you need to post more code :) the code for the controller tells us absolutely nothing about what you're tying to do.. or what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom validation.

Have a look here:
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules

An example:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';

    var $validate = array(
        'promotion_code' => array(
            'rule' => array('limitDuplicates', 25),
            'message' => 'This code has been used too many times.'
        )
    );

    function limitDuplicates($check, $limit){
        //$check will have value: array('promomotion_code' => 'some-value')
        //$limit will have value: 25
        $existing_promo_count = $this->find( 'count', array('conditions' => $check, 'recursive' => -1) );
        return $existing_promo_count < $limit;
    }
}
?>
```